# How do I override the cascade delete for a relation in Grails GORM?

Tags: grails, relational-database, grails-orm, foreign-key-relationship, h2

I'm having some problems with the GORM part of Grails. I am using Grails 1.3.4, together with H2.

In the database I have two tables **template** and **report**. On the GORM-level I have the two Domain classes `Template` and `Report`;

```
class Template {

static hasMany = [reports: Report]

...
}
```

and

```
class Report {

static belongsTo = [template: Template]

...
}
```

Default behaviour seems to be that when a `Template` is deleted, the deletion will be cascaded so that all `Report`s that it has will be deleted as well.
On the database level I tried to make the **template_id**-column in the **report**-table be a *ON DELETE SET NULL* foreign key , but that didn't work.

Is there some way to override the cascade delete?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The following should be added in the `Template` class:

```
static mapping = {
  reports cascade: 'none'
}
```

to be able to delete `Template`s without problems, this addition to the `Report` class is also necessary:

```
static constraints = {
  template(nullable: true)
}
```