# GROM create needless table with many-to-many mapping

Tags: java, hibernate, grails, grails-orm

I have problem about many-to-many mapping.

[Case]

- Account owns Community(owner)
- Community has many Account(members)

GORM create four tables:

- ACCOUNT
- COMMUNITY
- COMMUNITY_MEMBERS
- COMMUNITY_OWNER

GORM creates a table "COMMUNITY_OWNER (ACCOUNT_ID, OWNER_ID)". Why GORM creating this?

This table is not used.(Please look at Hibernate log) I want GORM to not create COMMUNITY_OWNER. My mapping is wrong?

Related Question: [cascade delete with many-to-many mapping in Grails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16855838/cascade-delete-with-many-to-many-mapping-in-grails)

[Domain Class]

```
class Account {

  String name

  static hasMany = [communities: Community]
  static belongsTo = [Community]
}

class Community {

  String name
  Account owner

  static hasMany = [members: Account]

  static mapping = {
    owner cascade: 'none'
  }
}
```

[TestCode]

```
def admin = new Account(name: 'admin').save(flush:true)
def user = new Account(name: 'user').save(flush:true)

def c = new Community(name: 'TestCommunity')

c.owner = admin

c.addToMembers(admin)
c.addToMembers(user)            
c.save(flush:true)

c.removeFromMembers(user)
c.save(flush:true)

c.delete(flush:true)
```

[Hibernate Log]

```
INFO  hbm2ddl.SchemaExport  - Running hbm2ddl schema export
DEBUG hbm2ddl.SchemaExport  - import file not found: /import.sql
INFO  hbm2ddl.SchemaExport  - exporting generated schema to database
DEBUG hbm2ddl.SchemaExport  - drop table account if exists
DEBUG hbm2ddl.SchemaExport  - drop table community if exists
DEBUG hbm2ddl.SchemaExport  - drop table community_members if exists
DEBUG hbm2ddl.SchemaExport  - drop table community_owner if exists
DEBUG hbm2ddl.SchemaExport  - create table account (id bigint generated by default as identity, version bigint not null, name varchar(255) not null, primary key (id))
DEBUG hbm2ddl.SchemaExport  - create table community (id bigint generated by default as identity, version bigint not null, name varchar(255) not null, owner_id bigint not null, primary key (id))
DEBUG hbm2ddl.SchemaExport  - create table community_members (community_id bigint not null, account_id bigint not null, primary key (community_id, account_id))

<<Why create?>> 
DEBUG hbm2ddl.SchemaExport  - create table community_owner (account_id bigint not null, owner_id bigint not null)

DEBUG hbm2ddl.SchemaExport  - alter table community add constraint FKA7C52FE92BBE477B foreign key (owner_id) references account
DEBUG hbm2ddl.SchemaExport  - alter table community_members add constraint FK5A8DA6C3C4A6EE81 foreign key (community_id) references community
DEBUG hbm2ddl.SchemaExport  - alter table community_members add constraint FK5A8DA6C398BAC5C1 foreign key (account_id) references account
DEBUG hbm2ddl.SchemaExport  - alter table community_owner add constraint FK12E232DD98BAC5C1 foreign key (account_id) references account
DEBUG hbm2ddl.SchemaExport  - alter table community_owner add constraint FK12E232DD8BE4BF77 foreign key (owner_id) references community
INFO  hbm2ddl.SchemaExport  - schema export complete

<<community_owner not used>>
DEBUG hibernate.SQL  - insert into account (id, version, name) values (null, ?, ?)
DEBUG hibernate.SQL  - insert into account (id, version, name) values (null, ?, ?)
DEBUG hibernate.SQL  - insert into community (id, version, name, owner_id) values (null, ?, ?, ?)
DEBUG hibernate.SQL  - update account set version=?, name=? where id=? and version=?
DEBUG hibernate.SQL  - update account set version=?, name=? where id=? and version=?
DEBUG hibernate.SQL  - insert into community_members (community_id, account_id) values (?, ?)
DEBUG hibernate.SQL  - update account set version=?, name=? where id=? and version=?
DEBUG hibernate.SQL  - update community set version=?, name=?, owner_id=? where id=? and version=?
DEBUG hibernate.SQL  - delete from community_members where community_id=? and account_id=?
DEBUG hibernate.SQL  - delete from community_members where community_id=?
DEBUG hibernate.SQL  - delete from community where id=? and version=?
```

Comment: I don't see `community_owner` in hibernate log.

Comment: Hibernate Log was missing. I'm sorry, please look again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at your mapping, I believe your case is slightly off (as well as the mapping). Did you mean to say ...

> Account has many Community (as 'communities') 
>   Community has many Account (as 'members')

this would be a true many-to-many. Also from your mapping, I'm assuming you'd like Account to be the owning side of the many-to-many. If this the case, then you can do something like the following.

```
class Account {
 ..
 static hasMany = [communities: Community]
 static mappedBy = [communities: 'owner']  //<-- will not work without this mapping
} 

class Community {
 ..
 static belongsTo = [owner: Account] //<-- assumes Account is owner
 static hasMany = [members: Account]
}
```

NOTE: the `belongsTo` in Community assumes Account will be the "owner". The mappedBy is needed otherwise Grails will blow up (here's a [discussion about it](http://grails.1312388.n4.nabble.com/Many-to-Many-problem-tt3297820.html#a3297866)).

You'll end up with the Account and Community tables and a third mapping table - no fourth table.

- the mapping table will handle the Community "has many members" relationship
- the Account "has many communities" relationship is handled by a foreign key on the Community table back to Account.

Comment: Your guess is right. I have fixed this problem. Thank you for the thorough explanation! I was able to understand thanks to you.